# Eventbrite user data input validation

Tags: validation, input, eventbrite

I am using Eventbrite for number of events. I would like to restrict the user providing incorrect information using input validation. I had a look at their settings which only identifies blank or basic validation such as email.

Is there any way to validate the input data when customised field is used? Otherwise, are there any other alternative apps which support this?